# SELECT on 2 Tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to update a report (report builder) on SQL Server, which is based upon a stored procedure.
The stored procedure as is - queries 2 tables via INNER JOIN but was only designed to display data from 1 table.
I'm trying to get it now to also display some data from the 2nd table.
While it executes fine, its not displaying any data from the 2nd table.

Code:

```
SELECT n.ID, COMPANY, TITLE, EMAIL, FULL_NAME, chapter, n.member_type, ng.INDUSTRY_CLASS
from name n
inner join name_general ng on n.id = ng.id
WHERE MEMBER_TYPE in ('A','B','C','D', 'E','F','G')
and n.STATUS = 'A'  
and N.EMAIL <> ''
and ng.no_mail = 0   
and (
        ( charindex ( chapter,'WA') > 0 ))
```

This was originally written by past people & it works as wanted, and the only thing I've added is the `ng.INDUSTRY_CLASS` within the select statement.  But when this is executed, no data displays for INDUSTRY_CLASS

*Obviously this is a partial extract of the stored procedure.

*Running on Server 2016 / SQL Server 2016

Comment: Assuming you're getting rows returned (with populated Company, Title, Email, etc.), and you're saying that the INDUSTRY_CLASS value is showing as "Null" (is that what you're seeing?), then clearly there is no value set for the INDUSTRY_CLASS column.  If you believe the JOIN is valid (ie. the correct "name" and "name_general" rows are being related by their respective "id" column values), then SQL is going to show what's contained within that field

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, ignore this question.

I realized that `INDUSTRY_CLASS` is on the Company Record & not an Individual's record.

Its a badly designed DB, in this same `name` table we have rows of people & rows of companies.
Obviously therefore both people & companies have the same fields.
The `INDUSTRY_CLASS` field is null for people, as that data is with a Company.

So both People and Companies have `n.id` in the name table & they also have `n.co_id`.
On a record for a person the `n.co_id` is just the `n.id` of the company from the same table.

This was the design of the CRM Manaufacturer... all im doing is querying the CRM db.